# Histogram of time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

How can I plot a histogram of times?

```
['09:00', '23:30', '19:05', '09:00', '01:00'...#list
```

Given the function takes input as the bin size in minutes.

Comment: Where is your problem - to plot a histogram or to convert strings to minutes?

Comment: @Alex.S I can convert to time object using `pattern = '%H:%M'; time_f=[strptime(x, pattern) for x in times] ;`

Comment: @Alex.S But I am confused on how to plot with variable minutes as bin size.

Comment: Something like `plt.hist(data, bins=[0, 30, 60, 90, 120])` maybe

Comment: @Alex.S The bins should be like `00:00,00:30 ,1:00...`. How do you think I can do that?

Comment: You can calculate the number of minutes from midnight `for x in time_f:
 x.tm_hour*60 + x.tm_min` and the plot a histogram of integers liek `plt.hist(minutes, bins=[0, 30, 60, 90, 120,...])`