# TypeError histogram of time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot times by each hour

```
    time_new=[x[:2]+":"+x[2:] for x in time_cleaned]        
    hour_list = [t[:2] for t in time_new]
    print hour_list
    numbers=[x for x in xrange(0,24)]
    labels=map(lambda x: str(x), numbers)
    plt.xticks(numbers, labels)
    plt.xlim(0,24)
    pdb.set_trace()
    plt.hist(hour_list)
    plt.show()
```

I get this error `TypeError: 'len() of unsized object'` in line `plt.hist(hour_list)`

```
pprint(time_new)
['09:00',
 '23:30',
 '19:05',
 '09:00',
 '01:00',
 '02:00',
 '19:00',
 '05:30',
 '04:00',
 '20:00',
 '23:30',
 '10:30',
 '20:00',
 '05:0',
 '21:30',
 '17:30',
 '04:55',
 '13:45',
 '08:40',
 '13:00',
 '06:00',
 '19:45',
 '09:00',
 '14:30',
 '09:00',
 '10:30',
 '23:07',
 '19:00',
 '23:40',
 '20:30',
 '19:30',
 '06:00',
 '05:30',
 '24:00',
 '20:30',
 '19:00',
 '15:05',
 '14:15',
 '19:20',
 '14:00',
 '15:15',
 '21:00']
(Pdb)
```

Edit:
Fixed it by:

```
hour_list = [int(t[:2]) for t in time_new]
```

By I am incorrect hist.
[image]

Edit 2:
[image]

Comment: How is this different from your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451265/histogram-of-time)?

Comment: This is primitive code, works only on number of hours. I refering to the error here. I can't understand the error.  `len(hour_list)` seems to work fine.

Comment: There is insufficient data here to reproduce your error, post raw input data and your code to make your df

Comment: Your edit is not an edit, it's an answer.  And, in fact, it's the answer given by @rurp below (so it would be a nice gesture to accept his answer, even if you'd found it yourself).  Don't try to ask a new question in an edit to the old one - it just makes everything confusing for readers who find this question (e.g. from google)

Comment: My recommendation is that you take the two histograms from the question and make a new question about how you can get the exact format of 24 bins you want (e.g. - if passing `bins=24` doesn't work for you, why not?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to plot strings as values. Try changing hour_list to:

```
hour_list = [int(t[:2]) for t in time_new]
```

Comment: Thanks! But please check edit I solved that. I am having a diff. issue though.

Comment: The histogram is showing how many times each hour occurred. What would you like it to show?

Comment: There should be 24 bins then?

Comment: You can pass in the number of bins you want as an optional argument.     plt.hist(hour_list, bins=24)

Comment: I have tried that it doesn't fix. Check edit 2. I wish the histogram to be centred aroung the number

Comment: Good question, `plt.hist(hour_list, bins=np.arange(24)-0.5)` will work. This link has it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083051/matplotlib-xticks-not-lining-up-with-histogram

Comment: Still face an issue. Let's follow this up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453225/incorrect-bin-orientation